# Edit comma seperated fields

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

Input:

```
1,012018,111
2,1-2018,111
3,10-2018,111
```

Output:

```
1,01/2018,111
2,01/2018,111
3,10/2018,111
```

How can i achieve that which meaning edit of month and year to be mm/yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU Awk, using `patsplit` to split the second comma delimited field into subfields of at most two decimal digits:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} {patsplit($2,a,/[0-9][0-9]?/); $2 = sprintf("%02d/%d%d", a[1], a[2], a[3])} 1' file
1,01/2018,111
2,01/2018,111
3,10/2018,111
```

If Perl is an option

```
perl -F, -lpe '
  $F[1] =~ s{(\d\d?)-?(\d+)}{sprintf "%02d/%d", $1, $2}e; 
  $_ = join ",", @F
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

*sed  -e 's/^(.*),(.*),(.*)/\2/g' -e 's/([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{4})/\1-\2/g' file*

s/^(.*),(.*),(.*)/\2/g - splits based on commas and gets 2nd value
s/([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{4})/\1-\2/g - splits and inserts '-' between year and month

Answer (score 0):

sed  -e 's/^(.*),([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{4}),(.*)/\1,\2-\3,\4/g' test.txt

- ^(.*), = capture until first ',' and stored in \1
- ([0-9]{1,2}) = capture 1 or 2 digit number and store in \2
- ([0-9]{4}) = capture 4 didit no and store in \3
- ,(.*) \4 = capture the rest from ',' and store it in \4
- And replace accordingly